# EF 6 "Unable to load the specified metadata resource" -- but I'm not using edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, metadata, edmx

Sorry if this has been asked, but I've gone through all of the other posts I can find and everyone seems to be using an EDMX, and not a "production" database.

I get the following error:

System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

when attempting to access my application. My connection string is as follows:

```
<add name="FormAssemblyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.FormAssembly.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.FormAssembly.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.FormAssembly.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server\instance;initial catalog=dbname;user id=userid;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This works perfectly if I am running it locally and it connects to the edmx with the following connection string, but as soon as I put it on our UAT server and point it to the database, I get that error.

```
<add name="FormAssemblyEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\FormAssembly.mdf;Initial Catalog=FormAssembly;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I really have no idea where to start. The database appears up to date, the user has access, and the server has access to the SQL server.

I have also tried replacing the res://*/ with res://FormAssembly/ and res://FormAssembly.dll/, but the former results in the same error, and the latter says the dll can't be found (the DLL is in the bin directory).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Travis

Comment: If you look at your first connection string, there's a spot that specifies the connection to the database while referencing the edmx.  You still need to reference the edmx on the UAT server, you just need to change the inner connection string to the UAT database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure what you mean. If I look for edmx in the first connection string, I don't see anything. Is it in the metadata?

Comment: Look at your first connection string again... this is there: `res://*/Models.Entities.FormAssembly.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;***provider connection string=...***`. Inside that is a second connection string that points to the actual database.  That's what you need to change in your UAT environment.

Comment: Yeah the connection string property is already set to my UAT database correctly, I modified it for my post. If you're referring to the res:// stuff under metadata, that also exists in the connection string to our production database and it works fine. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your UAT connection string should be: `<add name="FormAssemblyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.FormAssembly.csdl|res://*/Mod‌​els.Entities.FormAssembly.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.FormAssembly.msl;provider=‌​System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\FormAssembly.mdf;Initial Catalog=FormAssembly;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />` .. you're missing the metadata part in the UAT connection string.

Comment: Wouldn't that point to a local database? When the program is on UAT or production, I don't want to pointing to a local .mdf file, I want it to point to a database hosted on SQL server.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something then - which connection string is your UAT server, and which one is your development machine?

Comment: The top one that I modified to point to "server\instance" is my UAT one. It should point to SQL server, and not a local mdf. The second one I posted may not even be relevant, but I figured I would post it as that does work locally and doesn't give an error.

Comment: If you're not using an edmx, then get rid of all the meta data tags and just use `data source=server\instance;initial catalog=dbname;user id=userid;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` as your connection string then?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay on this.. got pulled off for a bit. Yeah, my confusion came from us switching between using an EDMX and code first. The production version had the metadata connection string because it is using an EDMX. When we switched to code-first obviously that had to go. 

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `metadata` part of my connection string was malformed.

The following connection string worked in my case:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Northwind.csdl|res://*/Northwind.ssdl|res://*/Northwind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```